# how to use sub grid results in another subgrid in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, subgrid

I got stuck in a situation where I have to deal with the following scenerio:

I need to add some users for meeting using sub grid view , and the users I have selected for the meeting should needs to be available in my other sub grid section which is (discussion point), from where I can select only those users which I selected them in meeting sub grid.

Thanks,
Haseeb

Answer (score 1):

Never came across such scenario but I think you can achieve this as following:

1. Register plugin on associate message (e.g. [Like This](http://orwin.ca/2011/07/05/crm-2011-plugin-triggering-off-associate-message/)) and check the association between you main entity and users selected for meeting.
2. On Association between Meeting user and main entity, also associate discussion group user and main entity programmatically (inside plugin). e.g. [associate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309247.aspx)

Let me know if it work for you.